# Custom Taxonomies for Custom Post Types in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type, taxonomy

I am in process of creating multiple custom post types on a Wordpress build.
To manage these post types, I am also creating custom taxonomies as opposed to the standard Wordpress "category" ones.

Here is the code I have used directly in the functions.php file to create the first taxonomy called "zone", but I now want to create a second custom Taxonomy.

If I replicate the code or alter the code, I get varying php errors.
Has anyone created multiple taxonomies before and has the solution?

```
/*Add zone category start*/
function tr_create_my_taxonomy() {
register_taxonomy(
'space-zone',
'spaces',
array(
'label' => __( 'Zone' ),
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'space-zone' ),
'hierarchical' => true,
)
);
}
add_action( 'init', 'tr_create_my_taxonomy' );
/*Add zone category end*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is example how to do it multiple times

```
function register_custom_taxonomies() {
    // Taxonomy 1
    $taxonomy1_labels = array(
        'name' => 'Taxonomy 1',
        'singular_name' => 'Taxonomy 1',
        // Add more labels as needed
    );

    $taxonomy1_args = array(
        'labels' => $taxonomy1_labels,
        'public' => true,
        // Add more arguments as needed
    );

    register_taxonomy('taxonomy1', 'your_post_type', $taxonomy1_args);


    // Taxonomy 2
    $taxonomy2_labels = array(
        'name' => 'Taxonomy 2',
        'singular_name' => 'Taxonomy 2',
        // Add more labels as needed
    );

    $taxonomy2_args = array(
        'labels' => $taxonomy2_labels,
        'public' => true,
        // Add more arguments as needed
    );

    register_taxonomy('taxonomy2', 'your_post_type', $taxonomy2_args);


    // Taxonomy 3
    $taxonomy3_labels = array(
        'name' => 'Taxonomy 3',
        'singular_name' => 'Taxonomy 3',
        // Add more labels as needed
    );

    $taxonomy3_args = array(
        'labels' => $taxonomy3_labels,
        'public' => true,
        // Add more arguments as needed
    );

    register_taxonomy('taxonomy3', 'your_post_type', $taxonomy3_args);


    // Add more taxonomies as needed
}

add_action('init', 'register_custom_taxonomies');
```